# Resolution tab missing in new ADT Bundle for android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the emulators size and the resolution tab is missing. I dont want to create a new device definition. IS there any other way to change the size of the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, go to:

C:\Users\YOURUSER\.android\avd

Then you'll see your AVD name, there will be a folder `YOURAVDNAME.AVD` folder, go inside that folder
Then if you have a ready profile for your size, open `config.ini` and find
`skin.path=`    and    `skin.name=`

parameters and change them.

Otherwise, you can open `hardware-qemu.ini` and locate 
`hw.lcd.width` and `height` and `depth` and other options and change them.

If you are using linux, your .android folder is in your home folder (if you haven't moved)

Comment: If you are using windows, you can't open those files in notepad, as they have Linux line endings, so you may need Notepad++ or similar editors

Comment: Also don't forget to have backup of files you edit, have a backup, then try to change parameters